# Nodejs & TypeORM Transaction Confusion

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, typeorm

I have confusion and I couldn't resolve it from the TypeORM documents.

Here is my function that is used as request handler and it is using transaction taken from getManager()

```
static makeTransaction = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    try {
        // check if the account ids are same
        const { senderAccountId, receiverAccountId, amount } = req.body;

        let senderAccount = await findEntityById(getRepository(Account), senderAccountId);
        let receiverAccount = await findEntityById(getRepository(Account), receiverAccountId);
        senderAccount.balance -= amount;
        receiverAccount.balance += amount;
        await validateOrReject(senderAccount);
        await validateOrReject(receiverAccount);
        const tempEntity = MyEntity.create({
            amount,
            receiverAccount: receiverAccount,
            senderAccount: senderAccount,
        });

        await validateOrReject(tempEntity);

        const accounts = await getManager().transaction(async transactionManager => {
            await transactionManager.save(senderAccount);
            await transactionManager.save(receiverAccount);

            return transactionManager.save(tempEntity);
        });

        return res.status(200).json({
            error: null,
            data: true,
        });
    } catch (e) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: "Transaction wasn't successfull" });
    }
};
```

So when I put a catch function for the last saving (only it fails and first 2 of them runs correctly), it gives "Query runner already released. Cannot run queries anymore" error.

When I change the flow like this, it works and I really wonder the reason because in [documents](https://typeorm.io/#/transactions) there are saving operations for different entity types and this is what I'm trying to do too.

```
static makeTransaction = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    try {
        // check if the account ids are same
        const { senderAccountId, receiverAccountId, amount } = req.body;

        let senderAccount = await findEntityById(getRepository(Account), senderAccountId);
        let receiverAccount = await findEntityById(getRepository(Account), receiverAccountId);
        senderAccount.balance -= amount;
        receiverAccount.balance += amount;
        await validateOrReject(senderAccount);
        await validateOrReject(receiverAccount);
        const tempEntity = MyEntity.create({
            amount,
            receiverAccount,
            senderAccount,
        });
        await validateOrReject(tempEntity);

        const transactionRes = await getManager().transaction(async transactionManager => {
            return transactionManager.save([tempEntity, senderAccount, receiverAccount]);
        });

        return res.status(200).json({
            error: null,
            data: transactionRes[0],
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        return res.status(400).json({ error: "Transaction wasn't successfull" });
    }
};
```

I want to learn the reason for that and any kind of idea or help is appreciated, thank you in advance.